# Easy LINQ-way to take n distinct items from an (infinite) IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generator, distinct

I have a generator-like infinite `IEnumerable` source from which I want to take n distinct items. Is there an easy LINQ-style way to do so (which is still fast)?

If there is no simple way, is the algorithm I've come up with a good idea?:

1. Take n items
2. Call Distinct
3. Call Count
4. If Count < n

   5. Take n - Count items
   6. Concat those and goto 2
5. End

Comment: What's wrong with `.Distinct().Take(n)`?

Comment: @juharr: Uhm, nothing, I just assumed it doesn't work. Is it faster than my proposed algorithm? How does it work internally?

Comment: It creates a HashSet and then it iterates the collection and attempts to put the item in the HashSet.  If it wasn't already in the HashSet it yields the value.  https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs,4ab583c7d8e84d6d

Comment: So it consumes 2*n memory, but that's ok I guess. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just call `Distinct` before `Take` to take n distinct elements:

```
var nDistincItems = source
    .Distinct()
    .Take(n);
```

Comment: This will not produce the _full_ batch size of `n` when it encounters a few _non distinct_ items produced by the "infinite enumerable"

Comment: @clarkitect Only if the collection has less than n distinct items.

Comment: Will this work with an infinite input data source? It's impossible to say without seeing the OPs code, but I can't imagine Distinct will work with infinite input by default.

Comment: @IanNewson: Didn't believe it either, however, it looks like it works...

Comment: @IanNewson Yes it will.  The only potential issue is if the infinite collection never has more than n distinct items, as then it will result in an infinite loop

Comment: @IanNewson Yes it will. `OrderBy` for instance would have been an issue, but `Distinct` doesn't need to know the full set to be able to work